# android: get geographic region?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, region

I have not seen anything in the APIs that gives you the region that a specific country is in.  For example, I can't list all the countries in the Latin America/Baltic regions of the world with any of the methods that are available.  Is there something I overlooked?  Will I have to build my own DB for this task?

Comment: region is not an geographic term. country and continent is. so first you ask yourself who defines what a region is.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://ws.geonames.org API. e.g

```
http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode?lat=53.3428&lng=6.2661&type=json
```

but you can get the address using the in built [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) API and grab the country information from the address.

Comment: I need the region specifically =(  So if I looked up Mexico with Country Code MX, I want to get Latin America.  I guess there's no API in Android to do this so the only option is to make my own mapping.